# asp.net imageurl uses physical path for testing

Tags: webforms, path, imageurl

I know that we can't use physical path when the webpage is deployed. 
But here is my problem: I'm developing an Application for C# winform and Asp.net webform, the Data folder for the app is huge and I need to put that folder separately from the projects' folders cause it would be convenient to backup my projects to Google drive. The C# winform is easy to link the physical path, but the asp.net webform forces me to put the Data folder inside the project.

My current solution is: putting the Data folder inside the asp.net webform project and link that folder to the C# winform. But it wouldn't be convenient to backup the webform.

But is there any way I can use physical path with asp.net webform just for testing?

Thanks for reading.

Answer (score 0):

You can put the folder external to web app folder, then place the path in Web.Config Under AppSettings as

```
<appSettings>
     <add name="Data_Folder_Path" value="C:\Path\to\Data\Folder" />
 </appSettings>
```

Then in code behind or elsewheere you need the data path you use Configuration class to read the path value:

```
var dataFolderPath = System.Configuration.ConfigurationManager.AppSettings["Data_Folder_Path"]
```

Comment: it's not working, the System.Configuration.ConfigurationManager.AppSettings["Data_Folder_Path"] returns the string path and nothing more, it can't change the fact that it's still physical path.

Comment: I may have posted too soon without asking. What do you want to do with data folder inside web app? To store database files? Logs?

Comment: @ Kofi Amparbeng : The Data folder contains image files which are used for my webform.

Comment: Then I suggest you create a separate static website in solution which is mapped to the data folder. Then all references from web app will be full http urls to that site. This way you get to share the data folder with winforms and web app

Comment: Also, during deplyment to production, you create the static site and one for web app with same method

Answer (score 0):

You can make use of server.mappath as shown below

`Server.MapPath("~/" + folderName + nameOfFile)`

to get the location of the files. 
You may save the names of the files on your database and retrieve them when needed.